# MVVMLight Multiple Listbox Selection

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

I have an ItemsContol bound to a Country model - which look like this.

---

Country
--int Id
--string Name
--List Counties

---

In the DataTemplate of the ItemsControl there's a Listbox - which is bound to the Counties property.

So what I want is only one item in any of the listboxes be selected at any one time.

For example:
I have an item selected in the first listbox and I click an item in the second listbox, then the first listbox shouldn't have any selected items.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a SelectedCounty property to your Country object.  Then you can bind the `SelectedItem` on your `ListBox` to that property.  Then in code manually set all others to null.  Something like so

```
Country.OnPropertyChanged += (s,e) => 
    {
         if(e.PropertyName == "SelectedCounty")
         {
             foreach(Country country in MyCountries)
                 if(country != sender)
                     country.SelectedCounty = null;
         }
    }
```

Comment: I was just about to delete this post cause I sorted it out. That example you used would work, but it's not very elegant IMO. I create a CountryViewModel and had a SelectedCounty in there and when it changed I broadcast a Message and in each of the CountryViewModels I had a Registered for the notifications - and if it's not in the same ViewModel then I'll set it to null - easy peasy....I wish :) thanks for taking the time to reply anyway - appreciated.

Comment: @IrishJoker: And that was awesome. You can make an answer as well.

Comment: @IrishJoker: If I understand it correctly, you're setting the SelectedCountry to null. If so, it'll again broadcast a message. So before broadcasting the change notification check if it's not null.

Comment: @Veer - Yeah I'm already doing that along with checking that the current SelectedCounty isn't the same as the one that sent it. I have it all working now in my test app nicely - now all I need to do is use it in my production app :) Fun times :P

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference here's the solution I'm using - it resides in the CountryViewModel

```
    private CountyModel _selectedcounty;
    public CountyModel SelectedCounty
    {
        get { return _selectedcounty; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedcounty = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCounty");

            if (value != null)
            {
                if (CountySelectedEvent != null)
                    CountySelectedEvent(value, EventArgs.Empty);

                Messenger.Default.Send<CountyModel>(value, "SelectedCounty");
            }
        }
    }

    public CountryViewModel()
    {
        Counties = new ObservableCollection<CountyModel>();

        Messenger.Default.Register<CountyModel>(this, "SelectedCounty",
            msg =>
            {
                if(msg != this.SelectedCounty && msg != null)
                    this.SelectedCounty = null;
            });
    }
```

Hope it helps someone :)